# Range Slider Custom Range Set

Tags: slider, zurb-foundation

- I'm trying to create a pricing slider. I'm using the Foundation Range Slider. This slider will tell you how much a product costs per month depending on the number of users. I have an image below the slider that has a scale the with number of users.
- I would like to customize each range item. So that when you're over 25 users, it will say $125. I would cusotmize each one and the last one would say Call Us!
- How do I accomplish this? Do I added values to the Data-Options?

http://stage.appdataroom.com/pricing/  I've pasted the code that I have in there now.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="small-12 centered-text" style="font-size:4rem;padding-bottom:20px;">
<span>$</span><span id="sliderOutput3"></span><span>/month</span>
</div>
<div class="small-12 columns">
<div class="range-slider" data-slider data-options="start: 125; end: 1125; step: 20;display_selector: #sliderOutput3;">
<span class="range-slider-handle" role="slider" tabindex="0"></span>

</div>

</div>
<div class="small-12 columns">
<img src="http://stage.appdataroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/pricing_ticker.png"/>
</div>

</div>
```

Thanks,

Ian